Does there exist a square matrix $B\neq O$ of order $n>1$, such that for every square matrix of order $n$ we have $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$?
This is a follow up to my previous question. There it was shown that for every square matrix $A$ of order $n$ there exists a square matrix $B\neq O$ of order $n$ with $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$.
The matrix $B$ that was constructed depends on $A$, and I'm wondering if we can find a $B$ that doesn't depend on $A$. So, given $n>1$ does there exist a square matrix of order $B$ such that for every square matrix of order $n$ we have $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$?
My intution tells me that this is not true. All I got is, by assuming that such a $B$ exists and by setting $A=B$ we get $2^n\det(B)=2\det(B)$ so that $B$ is singular (notice, $n>1$).

An idea: $B$ must have all zero eigenvalues (which implies that $B$ is nilpotent), since if a nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda$ existed, taking $A=-\lambda I$ yields $\det(A+B)=0$ but $\det(A) + \det(B) = (-\lambda)^n$.

If $B$ satisfies that condition, then $XBY$ also satisfies the condition for any invertible $X,Y$. So we can assume $B = I_r \oplus 0_{n-r}$. As you noted, $B$ is singular, so $r < n$. Now take $A = 0_r \oplus I_{n-r}$. Then $$\det(A) = \det(A) + \det(B) = \det(A+B) = \det(I) = 1.$$ This implies $A = I$, so $r = 0$, so $B = 0$.
